# Scala TypeTags or Manifest: Is it possible to determine if a type is a Value class?

Tags: scala

How do I find out if an object is a value class type, so that in the following example the test would print that the id is an AnyVal?

```
class MyId(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal

class AnyValSuite extends FunSuite {

  class Sample {
    def doIt[T](t: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Unit = {
      if(???) println(s"$t is an AnyVal")     
    }
  }

  test("Getting info if a type is a value class") {
    new Sample().doIt(new MyId(1))
  }
}
```

@senia: Thanks for the answer. Works perfect. Is it also possible to find out the primitive type the Value class is wrapping?

Extended the example now:

```
class MyId(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal
class NonAnyValId(val underlying: Int)

class AnyValSuite extends FunSuite {

  class Sample {
    def doIt[T](t: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Unit = {
      if(implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe <:< typeOf[AnyVal]) println(s"$t is an AnyVal")
      else println(s"$t is not an AnyVal")
    }
  }

  test("Getting info if a type is a value class") {
    new Sample().doIt(new MyId(1))
    new Sample().doIt(new NonAnyValId(1))
    new Sample().doIt(1)
  }
}
```

returns:

```
MyId@1 is an AnyVal
NonAnyValId@38de28d is not an AnyVal
1 is an AnyVal
```

**Edit 2:**
Now with wrapped type checking:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class MyId(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal
class NonAnyValId(val underlying: Int)

class AnyValSuite extends FunSuite {

  class Sample {
    def doIt[T](t: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Unit = {
      val tpe= implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe
      if(tpe <:< typeOf[AnyVal])  {
        println(s"$t is an AnyVal")
        val fields = tpe.members.filter(! _.isMethod)

        fields.size  match {
          case 0 => println("has no fields, so it's a primitive like Int")
          case 1 => {
            println("has a sole field, so it's a value class")
            val soleValueClassField = fields.head.typeSignature
            println("of type: " + soleValueClassField)
            if(typeOf[Int] == soleValueClassField) println("It wraps a primitive Int")
          }
          case 2 => throw new Exception("should never get here")
        }
      }
      else println(s"$t is not an AnyVal")
    }
  }

  test("Getting info if a type is a value class") {
    new Sample().doIt(new MyId(1))
    println
    new Sample().doIt(new NonAnyValId(1))
    println
    new Sample().doIt(1)
  }
}
```

returns:

```
MyId@1 is an AnyVal
has a sole field, so it's a value class
of type: Int
It wraps a primitive Int

NonAnyValId@3d0d4f51 is not an AnyVal

1 is an AnyVal
has no fields, so it's a primitive like Int
```

Just wondering if there is some easier solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just check if `T` is subtype of `AnyVal`.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

def doIt[T: TypeTag](t: T): Unit = {
  if(implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe <:< typeOf[AnyVal]) println(s"$t is an AnyVal")     
}

doIt(new MyId(1))
// $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$MyId@1 is an AnyVal
```

Comment: @flavian: what do you mean? Could you please add the code sample.

Comment: @senia Thanks works perfect! Is it also possible to get the wrapped primitive type of the value class?

Comment: @longliveenduro: There should be one and only field in `value class`, so you could find this field using scala reflection.

Comment: @senia Thanks with your hint, I've get it going, but looks quite complicated. Maybe I did it to complicated?